# Negative Absolute Positioning, Removing Scrollbar

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

I am working on this site: http://waterwing.waterwing.ca/

The top right corner animation is perfect except for that it creates a horizontal scrollbar with the way it's positioned.

It's absolutely positioned -120px top and right. I'm just wondering how I can make it so it won't extend the body and will just hide itself once it hits the edge of the page so that there is no scrollbar.

The scrollbar seems to not be there on Windows Firefox but is there on Mac Firefox and Safari.

Thanks,
Wade

Answer (score 6, accepted):

wrap `#corner` in another div and set it to the dimension occupied by the end point of the animation as well as position absolute. set the overflow on this div to hidden that will keep it from bleeding off the page and triggering the scroll.

Comment: Yup. Hidden overflow is what you want.

Comment: Perfect, the div was too big on 1024 resolution also so I had to start it at a smaller size then grow it with jquery when you hover. I think everything's perfect now, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can also just put `overflow: hidden` on the body, works the same way and saves you a div

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your situation, but you can get scrollbars for a div, or for the whole page. When building a responsive website layout, I always write this CSS:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

And this prevents scrollbars appearing, cross-browser and cross-device.